# a href on mysql values php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello my idea here is to show values from my database so far I've been using this code.

```
   <td><?php echo @$get_display->student_id ?></td>
```

Now what I am going to do next is make the student_id value be able to redirect the user to
my search page via a href and the search page be able to retrieve the student_id so it may be able to search the student so far this is my code.
After my SQL select statement i declared.

```
     $student_id= $_GET['student_id'];
```

this is my code to a href to search page but i can't manage to make it working.

```
   <td  class="text"><a href="search_enroll.php?ID=<?php .$student_id ?>">
                    <?php echo @$get_display->student_id ?></a></td>
```

Any form of help is highly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<td class="text"><a href="search_enroll.php?ID=<?=$student_id; ?>"><?php echo $get_display->student_id ?></a>
 </td>
```

Comment: Thank you but still does not have that a href hyperlink.

Comment: Nvm found it and fixed. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: putting this on my search page to get it. cant identify student_id                  else if(!empty($_GET['student_id'])){
     $id = $_GET['student_id'];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Syntex error in your code.dot(.) does not allowed bofore variable $student_id.
I have modify your code check it

```
<td  class="text"><a href="search_enroll.php?ID=<?php echo $student_id; ?>">
                    <?php echo @$get_display->student_id; ?></a></td>
```

Comment: Hmmm same error as the one on top. Unidentified variable it cant get $student_id maybe i should try declaring it right?

Comment: You have complete php sentence using semicolon(;) in td also

Comment: Hmmmm there's something wrong it just will not retrieve the student_id to add to the link. .always undefined index.

Comment: You can use php isset function for check GET data like if(isset($_GET['student_id'])){$student_id=$_GET['student_id'];}